# 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

```
-(void)downloadResult:(id)data
{
   if([data isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
   {
       if ([data count]==3) 
       {
           if ([dataResultDictionary count]) 
           {
                [[dataResultDictionary objectForKey:[data objectAtIndex:0]] addObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[data objectAtIndex:1],[data lastObject], nil]];
           }
           else
           {
               [dataResultDictionary setObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[data objectAtIndex:1],[data lastObject], nil]] forKey:[data objectAtIndex:0]];
           }
           if([dataResultDictionary count])
           {
                if ([[dataResultDictionary objectForKey:[data objectAtIndex:0]] count] == requiredResultCount) 
                 {
                    [downloadControlQueue cancelAllOperations];
                    [downloadControlQueue release];
                    downloadControlQueue = nil;
                    processing = YES;
                    [self procesResultData];
                }
            }

      }
      else
      {
            BOOL errorResult = TRUE;

            if ([data count]) 
            {
                        if ([[data lastObject] isKindOfClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]]) {
                            if ([[data lastObject] count]) {
                                if ([[[[data lastObject] allValues] objectAtIndex:0] count]) {

                                    [dataResultDictionary setObject:[data lastObject] forKey:[data objectAtIndex:0]];
                                    errorResult = false;
                }

               }
          }
       }

            if(errorResult)
            {
                [dataResultDictionary setObject:@"" forKey:[data objectAtIndex:0]];
            }
            if ([dataResultDictionary count] == requiredResultCount) {
                [downloadControlQueue cancelAllOperations];
                [downloadControlQueue release];
                downloadControlQueue = nil;
                processing = YES;
                [self procesResultData];

            }
            }
        }


    }
```

I AM GETTING DATA FROM SERVER. I WANT SHOW DOWNLOAD RESULT IN % VALUE IN IMAGE. BUT I AM GETTING CRASH . INITIALLY THIS METHOD IS WOTKING. I AM SHOWING DATA UPTO 70% IN IMAGE BUT REST OF PART IS CRASHED
.HELP ME

Comment: Dude CAPSLOCK is ON.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your query, as suggested by rakeshNS, it seems that `[dataResultDictionary objectForKey:[data objectAtIndex:0]]` is not a `NSMutableArray`. Instead it is a `NSString`.

Why are you trying to `addObject:` in parsed array, which ,btw, is non-mutable (`NSArray`)? You should really rethink the parsing logic. If required create a separate model class to store the parsed data. You can create the mutable array and store values in this model class.

Answer (score 0):

In your case `[dataResultDictionary objectForKey:[data objectAtIndex:0]]` is not an array it is NSString. So you are getting exception. try

```
if ([dataResultDictionary count]) {
     if([[dataResultDictionary objectForKey:[data objectAtIndex:0]] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){
          [[dataResultDictionary objectForKey:[data objectAtIndex:0]] addObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[data objectAtIndex:1],[data lastObject], nil]];
     }
}
else
{
     [dataResultDictionary setObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[data objectAtIndex:1],[data lastObject], nil]] forKey:[data objectAtIndex:0]];
}
```

Comment: This will still crash, because OP is trying to mutate a non-mutable array. OP is calling `addObject:` on `NSArray`. But your have identified the reason for crash correctly.

Comment: How can you say [dataResultDictionary objectForKey:[data objectAtIndex:0]] is mutable array or un-mutable array without seeing source code ?

Comment: How can you add `isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]` check and not `isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]`? Simple answer is the JSON parser returns non-mutable instances in parsed dictionary.

Comment: Ok. Here 'data' is coming from server. But what about 'dataResultDictionary'? It may be a user created dictionary having a NSMutableArray object for some key.

Comment: If you see the code closely, you will come to know that the `dataResultDictionary` is getting populated directly from `data`.